# how to adjust the height of a selectbox child control list in qooxdoo

Tags: qooxdoo

I have a select box with exactyl 9 items and would like to adjust the hight in a manner that all items are shown. By default the ninth element ist hidden and the user needs to scroll down.

I have the following code:

```
var selectbox = new qx.ui.form.SelectBox());
var list = selectbox.getChildControl( 'list' );
list.setHeight( 600 );
```

This code has no effect to the child control list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maxListHeight property should do what you need

http://www.qooxdoo.org/current/api/#qx.ui.form.AbstractSelectBox~maxListHeight

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks.
Note: to complete my example:
setMaxListHeight is a member of selectbox not list